# what is meant by (void *) variable and (void *) & variable in C

Tags: c, pointers, casting

Normally a pointer variable can be typecasted to a void pointer by `(void *)Pointervariable` but I have seen a program where normal a `int` variable is used  as `(void *)variable` and that same `int` variable is also used as `(void *) &variable`.

what is the meaning of these two?

Comment: Can you provide a concrete code snippet?

Comment: Generic code...

Comment: stab in the dark: `(void *) variable`<-- the variable is probably a pointer of some sort, and is being cast to a `void *`. Similarly, `(void *) &variable` is casting _the address for `variable`_ to a `void *`, suggesting `variable` is **not** a pointer, but you need a generic void pointer

Answer (score 3):

That is to *consider* an integer value *as* a pointer (expecting to access the memory pointed out by that *integer* value), nothing else.

However, this is not a very good practice. Quoting the `C11`, chapter §6.3.2.3

> An integer may be converted to any pointer type. Except as previously specified, the
>   result is implementation-defined, might not be correctly aligned, might not point to an
>   entity of the referenced type, and might be a trap representation.

For a *safer* integer to pointer (and vice-versa) conversion, there are two types defined explicitly, `intptr_t` and `uintptr_t`. From chapter §7.20.1.4

> The following type designates a signed integer type with the property that any valid
>   pointer to void can be converted to this type, then converted back to pointer to void,
>   and the result will compare equal to the original pointer:
>
> ```
> intptr_t
> ```

and it's unsigned counterpart, `uintptr_t`.

The standard makes these types as *optional*, so, again, no guarantee of availability across all implementations.

However, regarding the `(void *) &variable` is to consider a pointer to a certain type as a pointer to `void`. This sometimes can be useful, if the pointer is later converted to the original type before dereferencing. That is perfectly defined behavior. Quoting the standard again (*emphasis mine*)

> **A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type.** If the
>   resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the referenced type, the behavior is
>   undefined. **Otherwise, when converted back again, the result shall compare equal to the
>   original pointer.**